Difference between Authentication, session, outer and current user in postgres
I know about the users in postgres but don't have correct idea about them.
The difference I know is

Authenticated user - The user who enters his credentials to login into postgres database.
Session user - The user who owns the session but I am confused whats the difference between session and auth user
Outer user - It's something related to function definer but don't have exact idea
Current user - The person who is executing the query

Can someone correct me in the above definitions and if some example can be given it will also be helpful

"Authenticated user" is the same as "session user", except that the latter can be changed with SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION by a superuser. The "current user" is the currently active role and can be changed with SET ROLE and by executing a SECURITY DEFINER function. I have never heard of an "outer user".
